# How do I shrink my Ubuntu partition and reabsorb the freed space into my Mac OS Mojave Partition?

Tags: dual-boot

How do I shrink my Ubuntu partition and reabsorb the freed space into my Mac OS Mojave Partition?

I started with 250 GB SSD, to which I allocated about 65 GB for Ubuntu like 3 years ago. I installed Ubuntu with the help of a friend and online tutorials. I'm not a whiz.

Now I'd like to shrink my Ubuntu partition. I'm willing to remove it if necessary, but it would be cool to keep it around in case I get into that stuff again.

So ideally I'd shrink it by about 40 GB and then add that space back to my main Mac partition.

I have 4 volumes. 1 is a recovery volume, 1 is the main volume, 1 is the Ubuntu volume, and 1 is something else. (I might have even put Windows on this thing... I honestly am not sure.)

Originally [posted on the AskUbuntu site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1160291/how-do-i-shrink-my-ubuntu-partition-and-reabsorb-the-freed-space-into-my-mac-os?noredirect=1#comment1932359_1160291) but someone commented it was off-topic there, so posting here in hopes of better results.

[image: Volumes screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

For this question, I created a partition called "Ubuntu" but not really Ubuntu. Just a random partition that's only 3 GB but it should work the same way.

First of all, you will have to go to Disk Utility and choose "Show All Devices"

[image]

Then click on the top Disk and click "Partition"

[image]

[image]

You can then click on the "Ubuntu" piece of the pie chart and change the size from 65 GB to 25 GB or whatever you want it to be.

[image]

Click "Apply", wait for the process to finish, then it should be resized! Comment if you have any problems.